# backlogを超えるリクエストで謎の1秒待ち

Tags: c++, network, tcp

ローカルホストでTCP接続と切断を繰り返すC++のクライアント/サーバーコードを書いて、実験していたところ、listen引数のbacklogを超えるリクエストの処理において、クライアントもサーバーも動いていない謎の1秒が挟まる現象が発生しました。この現象をご説明頂いた上で、対応方法を教えてください。

### 環境

Lubuntu 20.04 x86_64
gcc 9.4.0
C++17

### コード

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
const string& appname(const string& s = string()) {
    static string _appname;
    if (! s.empty()) _appname = s;
    return _appname;
}
using namespace std::chrono;
string timestr() {
    system_clock::time_point scp = system_clock::now();
    time_t t = system_clock::to_time_t(scp);
    tm lt;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << put_time(localtime_r(&t, &lt), "%Y/%m/%e %H:%M:%S") << "," << setw(3) << setfill('0') << duration_cast<milliseconds>(scp - system_clock::from_time_t(t)).count();
    return ss.str();
}
void log(ostream& out, const string& s) {out << timestr() << " " << appname() << ": " << s << endl;}
void log(const string& s) {log(cout, s);}
void log_error(const string& s) {log(cerr, s + ":" + strerror(errno));}
#define LOG_ERROR() log_error(string(__FILE__) +  ":" + to_string(__LINE__))
struct Sock {
    Sock(int sock): _sock{sock} {}
    ~Sock() {if (_sock >= 0) ::close(_sock);}
    operator int() {return _sock;}
    void close() {if (_sock >= 0) ::close(_sock); _sock = -1;}
private:
    int _sock;
    Sock(){} Sock(const Sock&){} Sock& operator=(const Sock&){return *this;}
};
#define IF_ERROR_RETURN(cond) if (cond) {LOG_ERROR(); return;}
int client(const int PORT = 8000, const size_t N = 0x100000) {
    auto func = [](auto id, int port) {
        string idhead{to_string(id) + ": "};
        auto log_with_id = [&](auto s){log(idhead + s);};
        Sock sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        IF_ERROR_RETURN(sock < 0);
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        IF_ERROR_RETURN(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr) <= 0);
        IF_ERROR_RETURN(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0);
        log_with_id("connection established");
        struct sockaddr_in local_address;
        socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(local_address);
        IF_ERROR_RETURN(getsockname(sock, (sockaddr*)(void*)&local_address, &addr_size) != 0);
        log_with_id("localport: " + to_string(ntohs(local_address.sin_port)));
        shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
        log_with_id("write shutdowned");
        shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD);
        log_with_id("recv shutdowned");
        sock.close();
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        string s{to_string(i)};
        log(s + ": started");
        func(i, PORT);
        log(s + ": finished");
    }
    return 0;
}
#define IF_ERROR_BREAK(cond) if (cond) {LOG_ERROR(); break;}
void server(const int PORT = 8000) {
    auto log_server = [](const string s) {log(string("server: ") + s);};
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int sock;
    Sock serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    IF_ERROR_RETURN(serverSock < 0);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    IF_ERROR_RETURN(bind(serverSock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0);
    IF_ERROR_RETURN(listen(serverSock, 5) < 0);
    while (true) {
        socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
        Sock sock = accept(serverSock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);
        IF_ERROR_BREAK(sock < 0);
        log_server("remoteport: " + to_string(ntohs(client.sin_port)));
        char buff[4096];
        ssize_t readlen = read(sock, buff, sizeof(buff));
        IF_ERROR_BREAK(readlen < 0);
        if (readlen != 0) log_server("read!!! not empty!!!");
        sock.close();
        log_server("closed");
    }
    serverSock.close();
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) {
    appname(argv[0]);
    if (argc > 1 && string(argv[1]) == "--server") {server(); return 0;}
    else {return client();}
}
```

### 確認方法

以下のスクリプトを実行してログを取る

```bash
trap 'pkill -P $$' INT
./maxbacklog_time --server&
server=$!
./maxbacklog_time
kill $server
```

### ログ

以下のように、クライアント(225)が何故か1秒ほど待たされている。

```
...
2022/10/27 18:44:31,859 ./maxbacklog_time: server: remoteport: 35178
...
2022/10/27 18:44:31,859 ./maxbacklog_time: 221: localport: 35200
...
2022/10/27 18:44:31,865 ./maxbacklog_time: 222: localport: 35206
...
2022/10/27 18:44:31,865 ./maxbacklog_time: 223: localport: 35222
...
2022/10/27 18:44:31,865 ./maxbacklog_time: 224: localport: 35232
...
2022/10/27 18:44:31,865 ./maxbacklog_time: 224: finished
2022/10/27 18:44:31,865 ./maxbacklog_time: 225: started
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: closed
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: remoteport: 35186
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: closed
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: remoteport: 35196
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: closed
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: remoteport: 35200
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: closed
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: remoteport: 35206
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: closed
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: remoteport: 35222
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: closed
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: remoteport: 35232
2022/10/27 18:44:31,867 ./maxbacklog_time: server: closed
2022/10/27 18:44:32,879 ./maxbacklog_time: 225: connection established
...
```

### 質問

現象をご説明頂き、同期I/O＆シングルスレッド＆(アプリケーション層での)送受信データの変更なしに、謎の1秒を挟まない方法があれば教えてください。

Comment: `cygwin64` on `windows10 Pro 21H2 x64` で実行してみたところそういう現象は確認されなかったので処理系固有な挙動なのかも。まあ普通はそういうポート枯渇させるようなコードを書く必然はないはずなので XY 問題なんでしょう。

Comment: TCPスタックの実装依存だと思いますよ。Cygwinは作りが特殊なので難しいですよね。

Comment: `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_abort_on_overflow` を 1にするのはどうですか？

Comment: それは失敗になってしまうので問題ですね。オーバーフローなのかどうかはクライアント側が分からないわけですし。。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 現象の説明

#### パケットログ

```
18:44:31.865734 IP localhost.35238 > localhost.8000: Flags [S], seq 2050667274, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2726005063 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:44:31.867175 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.35186: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005056], length 0
18:44:31.867183 IP localhost.35186 > localhost.8000: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005064], length 0
18:44:31.867284 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.35196: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005056], length 0
18:44:31.867290 IP localhost.35196 > localhost.8000: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005064], length 0
18:44:31.867383 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.35200: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005062], length 0
18:44:31.867393 IP localhost.35200 > localhost.8000: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005064], length 0
18:44:31.867455 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.35206: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005063], length 0
18:44:31.867479 IP localhost.35206 > localhost.8000: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005064], length 0
18:44:31.867541 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.35222: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005063], length 0
18:44:31.867566 IP localhost.35222 > localhost.8000: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005064 ecr 2726005064], length 0
18:44:31.867628 IP localhost.8000 > localhost.35232: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005065 ecr 2726005063], length 0
18:44:31.867651 IP localhost.35232 > localhost.8000: Flags [.], ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 2726005065 ecr 2726005065], length 0
18:44:32.879272 IP localhost.35238 > localhost.8000: Flags [S], seq 2050667274, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2726006076 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

一言で言えば謎の1秒はLinuxのSYNパケット再送時間です。

#### ログにサーバーとクライアントが交互に現れない理由

同期I/Oとシングルスレッドを使用し、事前に通信状況を確認せず読み書きしているのに、サーバーとクライアントが交互に現れないのは、クライアントが接続要求した際に出るSYNパケットをサーバーが受信すると、acceptが戻る前にTCPスタックがSYN-ACKを返しているためです。

http://arthurchiao.art/blog/tcp-listen-a-tale-of-two-queues/

クライアント側はSYN-ACKを受け取ると、ACKを返しつつconnectが戻るため、そのまま切断できて次の接続処理を開始できます。そのため、タイミングによっては、サーバーがacceptを処理する前に複数の接続/切断処理を実行できるわけです。

#### 謎の1秒の正体とは

サーバーではacceptキューがbacklog分貯まると、SYNパケットがそのまま捨てられるため、クライアントにはSYN-ACKが返りません。そのため、クライアント側からはSYNパケットの再送が1秒後に始まります。つまりクライアント側がSYNパケットが捨てられたことを検出するのに1秒かかるというわけです。

### 対応方法

#### 修正

<strike>acceptより前にSYN-ACKが返る以上、サーバーとクライアントが交互に動く保証はなく、そうなるとバックログ分acceptキューに溜まっていくことも抑えられません。アプリケーション層の授受データを変えない限り、対応は不可能に見えます。</strike>
clientが送信側のshutdownの後、readすれば次のコネクションを張りにいかないので、交互に動かすことができました。失念しててすみません。

```
@@ -53,6 +53,10 @@ int client(const int PORT = 8000, const
         log_with_id("localport: " + to_string(ntohs(local_address.sin_port)));
         shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
         log_with_id("write shutdowned");
+        char buff[4096];
+        ssize_t readlen = read(sock, buff, sizeof(buff));
+        IF_ERROR_RETURN(readlen < 0);
+        if (readlen != 0) log_with_id("read!!! not empty!!!");
         shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD);
         log_with_id("recv shutdowned");
                sock.close();
```

### 補足

サーバー→クライアントに1バイトだけ通信するとサーバーとクライアントが交互に動き、SYN再送は発生しません。

#### 追記

client側でreadをすることで通信データを加える必要がないことが分かりました。この補足は不要です。

```
@@ -51,6 +51,10 @@ int client(const int PORT = 8000, const
         socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(local_address);
         IF_ERROR_RETURN(getsockname(sock, (sockaddr*)(void*)&local_address, &addr_size) != 0);
         log_with_id("localport: " + to_string(ntohs(local_address.sin_port)));
+        char buffer;
+        ssize_t len = read(sock, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
+        IF_ERROR_RETURN(len < 0);
+        if (len == 0) {log_with_id("unexpected EOF!!!");}
         shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
         log_with_id("write shutdowned");
         shutdown(sock, SHUT_RD);
@@ -83,7 +87,9 @@ void server(const int PORT = 8000) {
         Sock sock = accept(serverSock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);
         IF_ERROR_BREAK(sock < 0);
         log_server("remoteport: " + to_string(ntohs(client.sin_port)));
-        char buff[4096];
+        char buff[4096]; buff[0] = 0;
+        IF_ERROR_BREAK(write(sock, buff, 1) < 0);
+        log_server("wrote 1byte");
         ssize_t readlen = read(sock, buff, sizeof(buff));
         IF_ERROR_BREAK(readlen < 0);
         if (readlen != 0) log_server("read!!! not empty!!!");
```