# std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point型をミリセカンドで表したい

Tags: c++

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

で表されるnowをミリセカンド単位で出力したいのですがどの様に記述すれば良いでしょうか。

```
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now) << std::endl;
```

ではエラーが出てしまい、出力できませんでした。

Comment: 現在時刻をミリ秒精度まで出力したい（例: `2022-12-16T12:00:00.123`）という意味でしょうか？

Comment: はい、yohjpさんの仰る通りです。

Answer (score 6):

C++コンパイラがC++20標準ライブラリに正しく対応していれば(※)、下記コードで期待通りの出力が得られます。
※: 2022年12月現在は、最新のMicosoft Visual C++でしか動作しません。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto now_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now);
  std::cout << now_ms << std::endl;
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oWdY5eK59

---

質問文中では[`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/chrono/steady_clock.html)を利用されていますが、このClockは「絶対に逆行しない時計」保証を与える代償として、実世界における時計と直接リンクしていません。2点間の経過時間(`duration`)を計算するための道具と考えた方がよいです。

通常の意味で「現在時刻」が必要であれば[`std::chrono::system_clock`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/chrono/system_clock.html)を用いて、動作環境のシステム時刻における現在時刻を取得します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
手元の環境がISO C++14なのですがこの環境でうまく記述する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: [dameoさん回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/92813)であればC++14環境でも動くと思いますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
duration_castで書く方法はありますか？（度々すみません。。）

Comment: [`duration_cast`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/chrono/duration_cast.html)は`duration`同士の型変換しか行えません。今回の目的に対しては適合しません（[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/)に聞こえます）

Answer (score 0):

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91865/backlog%e3%82%92%e8%b6%85%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b%e3%83%aa%e3%82%af%e3%82%a8%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e8%ac%8e%e3%81%ae1%e7%a7%92%e5%be%85%e3%81%a1)で使った**非推奨**の泥臭いコードも置いておきます。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

string timestr() {
    system_clock::time_point scp = system_clock::now();
    time_t t = system_clock::to_time_t(scp);
    tm lt;
    stringstream ss;
#ifdef _WIN32
    localtime_s(&lt, &t);
#else
    localtime_r(&t, &lt);
#endif
    ss << put_time(&lt, "%Y-%m-%e %H:%M:%S") << "." << setw(3) << setfill('0') << duration_cast<milliseconds>(scp - system_clock::from_time_t(t)).count();
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    cout << timestr() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Y7c7f9z3f